# Prefixing a two-word technical term with "sub-"

Tags: prefixes, technical

I have the term "verification code" and need a term for a particular code that is part of it. Normally, if the term were only "code", I'd use "subcode". How would I correctly prefix "verification code" with "sub-" such that the meaning is clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use "verification subcode".  You are possibly better off picking a term that denotes the function of the "subcode" and calling it a  prefix.

Comment: I disagree with this; to me, "verification subcode" would mean "the verification part of a code", rather than "part of a verification code".

Comment: This is a possible alternative meaning, however "sub-verification code" would definitely be incorrect.  This imprecision is part of the reason I suggest rephrasing to be more specific about the purpose of the subcode is a more appropriate solution.

Comment: Don't worry, I wasn't suggesting "sub-verification code". Also, by the way, you seem to have interpreted "prefix" as meaning "the first part of a code", but I'm quite certain that that's not what the OP meant.

Comment: Good point, I'd misparsed the question.  have removed the relevant sentence.